# AframeJS how to use other fonts like Helvetica bold in a text entity

Tags: aframe

i want to add the Helvetica-Bold font inside this text entity. Here is my code line to add it, just like how aframe explains in [it's docs  found here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/text.html#custom-fonts).

```
<a-entity scale=" 30 30 30" position="19 3.5 -19.4" text="font: fonts/helvetica.fnt; color: #737373; value: KASBOEK&reg; XVIII, pavilions;"></a-entity>
```

The text doesn't show up or work. Does someone have a work around this or a fix to use Helvetica-Bold as a font inside this entity?

Comment: Provide link with sample to reproduce.

Comment: Is the helvetica font in that directory?

Answer (score 0):

Fonts fnt or json must be included with png files

```xml
<a-entity scale=" 30 30 30" 
          position="19 3.5 -19.4" 
          text="font: fonts/helvetica.fnt; fontImage:fonts/helvetica.png
                color: #737373; value: KASBOEK&reg; XVIII, pavilions;">
</a-entity>
```